# passing an arugment to exec in python3

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, subprocess, parameter-passing, executable

I'm trying to call a script with params, that should be passed as an object not a string. However, when I'm using `subprocess.call()` it passes the string itself rather then the variable. How can I pass the object as argument in python3?

Example:

```
student = Student(id=3)
subprocess.call(my_script.py, student)
```

I want a to be passed as Student , so I could do:

```
id = student.id
```

inside my_script.py.
I thought about pickling student but it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do exactly what you want with `subprocess.call()`.
Is there any reason why you want to run `my_script.py` as a separate process?

Why not import it

```
import my_script as ms
```

and then use its functions?

```
ms.process_student(student)
```

Comment: I'm trying to execute it as a separate process since my main code is in python3 but I need this specific script to run with python2.. Is there any other to do it?